# Why am i getting these invalid characters before my file data?

Tags: c++, string, file, fstream, readfile

[image]

I am trying to read a file into a string either by `getline` function or `fileContents.assign( (istreambuf_iterator<char>(myFile)), (istreambuf_iterator<char>()));` 
Either of the way gives me the above output which shown in the image.

First way:

```
 string fileContents;
 ifstream myFile("textFile.txt");
 while(getline(myFile,fileContents))
 cout<<fileContents<<endl;
```

Alternate way:

```
 string fileContents;
 ifstream myFile(fileName.c_str());
 if (myFile.is_open())
  {
    fileContents.assign( (istreambuf_iterator<char>(myFile) ),
                       (istreambuf_iterator<char>()    ) );
    cout<<fileContents;
  }
```

Comment: Is the file utf encoded not ascii.? These might be the BOM in first 4 bytes.

Comment: @rlb its a simple text file.

Comment: Simple text ain't what it used to be, sadly. Why when I was a kid text was text. These days it's all read a byte-read a byte-read a byte-byte-byte! We done reading bytes yet? Every day when I get up, I have to read forty miles of bytes. Up hill. Young whipper-snappers an their goldurn UTF.

Answer (score 1):

The file begins with those characters, most likely a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to tell you what the encoding of the file is.

You probably are not able to see them in Windows Notepad because Notepad hides the encoding bytes.  Get a decent text editor that lets you see the binary of the file and you will see those characters.

Comment: Text files don't always have one, depends on how it's encoded. For UTF, the magic numbers are 0xFF and 0xFE. Raw ascii won't have magic numbers at all.

Comment: @EdMaster  

How should i fix it ?
What should i do to avoid these characters?
Do i need to apply any encoding techniques ??

Comment: In case this needs being said out loud: your input file is corrupted, generate the input file again, making sure your tool does not insert magic numbers it would not show you.

Comment: @EdMaster I already made 2 to 3 txt files and each one has same invalid characters

Comment: @EdMaster thanks I downloaded a file from internet. It works fine with my code.
Thanks

Comment: @cehnehdeh: `0xFF 0xFE` is the UTF-16LE BOM.  [Other possible BOMs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding) include `0xEF 0xBB 0xBF` (UTF-8), `0xFE 0xFF` (UTF-16BE), `0xFF 0xFE 0x00 0x00` (UTF-32LE) and `0x00 0x00 0xFE 0xFF` (UTF-32BE). And as you can see, there is an ambiguity between the UTF-16LE and UTF-32LE BOMs that you have to account for as well (if you need to handle UTF-32 data).

Comment: @EdMaster: the file is not corrupted, it is simply encoded. The OP's app needs to detect that encoding and process it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your file starts with a UTF-8 [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (bytes `0xEF 0xBB 0xBF`).  You are reading the file's raw bytes as-is and outputting them to a display that is using an OEM font for [codepage 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437).  To handle text files properly, especially Unicode-encoded text files, you need to read the first few bytes, check for a BOM (and there are [several you can look for](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding)), and if detected then seek past the BOM and interpret the remaining bytes of the file in the specified encoding, in this case UTF-8.